# Laravel Validation with or condition

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have text box which will accept number or alphabets based on my requirements

Ex: 1234 - correct,
    abcd - correct,
    123abc - wrong

So i need  `'my_texbox' => 'alpha|numeric'` as **or** condition but it was by default **and** condition.

Is there any way to achieve this other than custom validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

and

```
$arr=['name'=>'123'];
$rule=['name'=>array('regex:/(?:^([^a-b]*)$|^([^0-9]*)$)/')];
$accept=Validator::make($arr,$rule);
dd($accept->fails());
```

**Output**

1234 - correct, abcd - correct, 123abc - wrong